# Office.js - Outlook - saving a unsaved appointment using saveAsync

Tags: outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-app

In my main compose form in an Outlook add-in written in the new office.js API I want to be able to save a unsaved appointment.

By unsaved I mean that the user double-clicked on the calendar, wrote some data on the subject and didn't clicked "Save" just went straight to my add-in by opening the compose form.

When I call 
`Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync`
I'm getting following error displayed for the user:

`Error: the event couldn't be created on the server. Please try again.`

and a pop-up displays a similar message:

`Couldn't create the following event: [EVENT_NAME]`

any tips how to save this event?

Above behavior is on Outlook Web App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please unselect the All day checkbox on the appointment compose form and then call saveasync, it should work. This happens to be a known issue that we are addressing.

[All Day Checkbox on compose appointment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbE7i.png)

Comment: Is there any estimation when this bug will be resolved?

Comment: Is there an option to unselect that checkbox from JS code?

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? This works fine for us on Outlook for windows